# RedShift Spectrum UPDATE from External Schema Filling Disk

Tags: amazon-redshift, aws-glue, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have two archived tables that live in S3: s3_web and s3_events. I've created external tables in Glue and and external schema to access them. The data in these external tables is partitioned by "month" and "app". The data is stored as parquet files. Our cluster is dc2.large nodes.

I'm querying S3 using Spectrum and inserting that data into a dimension table in RedShift. Let's call that "dim_table"

In step 1 of my process, dim_table is defined as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dim_table (
    root_tstamp         TIMESTAMPTZ     ENCODE AZ64,
    page_view_id        VARCHAR(36)     ENCODE ZSTD,
    root_id             CHAR(36)        ENCODE LZO,
    page_urlhost        VARCHAR(255)    ENCODE ZSTD,
    page_url            VARCHAR(4096)   ENCODE ZSTD,
    domain_sessionid    CHAR(128)       ENCODE ZSTD
)
DISTSTYLE KEY
DISTKEY (root_id)
SORTKEY (root_tstamp);
```

In step 2, I successfully insert data from the external table, s3_web, into dim_table. This inserts 6,670,962 rows into dim_table:

```sql
WITH cte_x AS
(
    SELECT root_id, root_tstamp FROM client_dim_table_x WHERE root_tstamp >= '2021-09-01' AND root_tstamp < '2021-10-01'
UNION
    SELECT root_id, root_tstamp FROM client_dim_table_y WHERE root_tstamp >= '2021-09-01' AND root_tstamp < '2021-10-01'
)

SELECT
    wp.root_tstamp,
    wp.id AS page_view_id,
    wp.root_id
FROM cte_x AS ce
-- join external_schema.glue_data_catalog_table
JOIN external.s3_web AS wp
    ON ce.root_id = wp.root_id AND ce.root_tstamp = wp.root_tstamp
WHERE
    -- wp.month limits spectrum s3 scan to specified partition 
    wp.month = '2021-09-01 00:00:00';
```

The next bit (step 3) is what I can never get to work. It disk spills and fills Redshift disk.

After the step 2, dim_table has three of its six columns populated. Now I need to populate the remaining three columns with data from the second external table, s3_events:

```sql
UPDATE dim_table
    SET page_urlhost = ev.page_urlhost,
        page_url = ev.page_url,
        domain_sessionid = ev.domain_sessionid
FROM external.s3_events AS ev
    WHERE 
        ev.month = '2021-09-01 00:00:00' AND
        ev.app = 'cust_app' AND
        dim_table.root_id = ev.event_id AND
        dim_table.root_tstamp = ev.collector_tstamp;
```

EXPLAIN for that UPDATE statement looks like this:

```
XN Hash Join DS_DIST_INNER  (cost=96566590.64..2846962678000666.50 rows=322 width=1642)
 Inner Dist Key: ev.event_id
 Hash Cond: (("outer".root_id = ("inner".event_id)::character(16383)) AND ("outer".root_tstamp = ("inner".collector_tstamp)::timestamp with time zone))
  ->  XN Seq Scan on dim_table  (cost=0.00..66709.62 rows=6670962 width=94)
  ->  XN Hash  (cost=85836971.12..85836971.12 rows=2145923903 width=2072)
   ->  XN Partition Loop  (cost=0.00..85836971.12 rows=2145923903 width=2072)
    ->  XN Seq Scan PartitionInfo of external.s3_events ev  (cost=0.00..15.00 rows=1 width=0)
      Filter: (((app)::text = 'app_1'::text) AND (("month")::text = '2021-09-01 00:00:00'::text))
    ->  XN S3 Query Scan ev  (cost=0.00..42918478.06 rows=2145923903 width=2072)
      ->  S3 Seq Scan external.s3_events ev location s3:/path_to_files format:PARQUET (cost=0.00..21459239.03 rows=2145923903 width=2072)
```

I can see that the partition filters for month and app are being properly understood by spectrum.

This is the first time I've used Spectrum and I've been discovering it's limitations as I run into them. Is there anything I can do to optimize this? I'm trying to decide if I need to scale up just to get these tables built, or if I should be able to do this without blowing up RedShift.

Thank you

**UPDATE**:

After the update statement fails, in console I'm given the following info:

```
**Hash Join DS_DIST_INNER**
Alert: Distributed a large number of rows across the network
Solution: Review the choice of distribution key to collocate the join or aggregation
```

The external folder that I'm scanning is ~23gb of Parquet files, and I see that represented in the query plan in console:
[image: Console query plan of failed update]

What looks like the issue is that the statistics in the execution timeline in console show that much more data is being scanned, which I believe is a due to what caused the query alert, the large number of rows distributed across the network.

```
Statistics
Total rows scanned 265,766,848
Total data scanned 665.24 GB
```

If my external S3 data actually has that many rows, and it is only partitioned as granular as month, can I even fix the large distribution of rows? My base table, created in step 1, is DISTSTYLE KEY - could changing this have a positive effect on the distribution of rows in my query plan when running this update? I'll have to test this, regardless.

Thank you

**Experiment Results**:

1: How many matching "updates" are there in this query?

```sql
SELECT
  COUNT(1)
FROM
  dim_table
  JOIN external.s3_events AS ev
ON dim_table.root_id = ev.event_id
  AND dim_table.root_tstamp = ev.collector_tstamp
WHERE
  ev.month = '2021-09-01 00:00:00'
  AND ev.app = 'cust_app';
  
count  
---------
 4930895
```

Experiment #2: How many rows are being brought in from spectrum?

```sql
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM external.s3_events ev
WHERE
ev.month = '2021-09-01 00:00:00'
  AND ev.ap = 'cust_app';
  
count   
----------
 82648072
```

Experiment #3: How unique is the joining for the UPDATE to dim_table?

```sql
SELECT COUNT(1) as cnt
FROM dim_table 
GROUP BY root_id, root_tstamp
HAVING cnt > 1
ORDER BY cnt desc
LIMIT 1000;

cnt 
-----
   2
   ..
   2
22 rows
```

Experiment #4: How unique are the updates values coming from spectrum?

```sql
SELECT
  count(1) as cnt
FROM
  external.s3_events AS ev
WHERE
  ev.month = '2021-09-01 00:00:00'
  AND ev.app = 'cust_app'
GROUP BY
  ev.event_id,
  ev.collector_tstamp
HAVING cnt > 1
ORDER BYcnt desc
LIMIT 1000;
 cnt 
-----
   2
  ..
  2
307 rows
```

Looking at some vendor documentation tells me that:
"dim_table.root_id = events.event_id, which is a one-to-one join or a many-to-one join"

**UPDATE 2**:

To confirm the partition had been added to the external table, I tried added it with alter table, and received this error indicated it already existed: "ERROR:  [2021-09-01 00:00:00,cust_app] Partition entries already exist."
Info on partitions of external events table:

```sql
select tablename, values, location
from SVV_EXTERNAL_PARTITIONS
snowplow-# WHERE schemaname = 'external_schema';
      tablename      |                    values                     |                                                     location                                                     
---------------------+-----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 events              | ["2022-09-01 00:00:00","cust_app"]        | s3://pathto/events/month=2022-09-01 00:00:00/app=cust_app/
 events              | ["2022-09-01 00:00:00","cust_app_1"] | s3://pathto/events/month=2022-09-01 00:00:00/app=cust_app_1/
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your data so I'm inferring things.  First off that's a very high cost on that join.  I suspect that there are many rows updating the same row in the dim table.  Check your join conditions to make sure that you have a 1:1 join for these updates.

Every time a row is updated a new row is created and the old one invalidated.  You may need to preprocess your spectrum data to reduce it to only the needed rows for update (most recent match only).

Again what is going on is very dependent on your data so I'm making a number of assumptions.

If this doesn't match what is going on look at the actual execution report in the console and post that.  EXPLAIN only reports what it thinks will happen, not what actually happened.

=================================

Experiment #1:  How many matching "updates" are there in this query?

```
SELECT count(1) 
FROM dim_table
JOIN external.s3_events AS ev
WHERE 
        ev.month = '2021-09-01 00:00:00' AND
        ev.app = 'cust_app' AND
        dim_table.root_id = ev.event_id AND
        dim_table.root_tstamp = ev.collector_tstamp;
```

This shouldn't fill up the disks as no data is saved just a count of rows.  If this does fill up disks then you theory on not pruning spectrum data may be correct.

Experiment #2: How many rows are being brought in from spectrum?

```
SELECT count(1) 
FROM external.s3_events ev
WHERE ev.month = '2021-09-01 00:00:00' AND
    ev.app = 'cust_app';
```

I expect this to result in the scan row count as in your actual execution report - 38M.

Experiment #3: How unique is the joining for the UPDATE to dim_table?

```
SELECT count(1) as cnt
FROM dim_table
GROUP BY root_id, root_tstamp
HAVING cnt > 1
ORDER BY cnt desc
LIMIT 1000;
```

This should result in zero rows if the UPDATE WHERE clauses are correct.

Experiment #4:  How unique are the updates values coming from spectrum?

```
SELECT count(1) as cnt
FROM external.s3_events AS ev
WHERE 
    ev.month = '2021-09-01 00:00:00' AND
    ev.app = 'cust_app' 
GROUP BY ev.event_id, ev.collector_tstamp
HAVING cnt > 1
ORDER BY cnt desc
LIMIT 1000;
```

Even if dim_table rows are unique you could still be trying to update the same row many times.

There should be a 1:1 relationship between dim_table and s3_events rows based on the WHERE clause of the UPDATE.  If not there are be massive row explosion of intermediate results but the report will not show it since updating the same row over and over doesn't create a new row, just work and new zombie rows.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I ran the query again and in console I'm getting a query alert "Distributed a large number of rows across the network". I'll add more detail to the bottom of my original post

Comment: Please do.  Having a large amount of network traffic is what I'd expect but I think that the root cause is that the amount of data coming into the UPDATE from spectrum is way more that is needed.  This results in many things including a massive amount of data flying around the cluster network.  Just my working theory ATM.

Comment: Thank you. I've added more detail, as well as the row count of dim_table after the initial INSERT. I'm worried that spectrum is scanning all of the columns in my external s3_events parquet files, despite only needing 3 of them for the update. I'm not sure if SET in the UPDATE statement will act like a SELECT, allowing spectrum to scan only the columns required.

Comment: It's 7 columns - it needs the 4 in the where clause too - but I expect that reading more columns than necessary is the issue.  Could be wrong but this would be a significant miss on RS's part.  An UPDATE is a join in other clothes and I think the join is under qualified.  I'll update the answer with some experimental thoughts.

Comment: The results of experiment #2 are a little confusing - the count is much higher than expected. Experiment #3 and 4 returned 22 duplicate (root_id, root_tstamp) pairs in dim_table, which I'll have to investigate. Are these duplicates the likely the cause of this row explosion?

Comment: Interesting.  While there are duplicates which need to be understood, there doesn't look to be enough to create a disk full situation.  How much free space is there on the cluster before the query runs?

Comment: This leads me to think about alternative explanations.  One thought is that the spectrum partitioning isn't set up properly.  Now that I look closer at the SQL for month (the partition key) this seems likely.  Did you perform "ALTER TABLE <schema>.<table> ADD PARTITION(month=<value>) LOCATION 's3:...'" for each of the months in the external table?  (or the equivalent)  The partition key is not a value in the parquet files but a part of the s3 path.  You can check SVL_S3QUERY_SUMMARY and confirm that only the files for the month in question are parsed.

Comment: There should be between 800 and 900GB free, across 16x dc2.large nodes. Each time the disk full error appears to occur on a different node. For the sake of it, I removed the 22 duplicate rows and still filled the disk. I've also confirmed from svl_s3partition that only one partition is qualified and scanned in my query, as expected. Total partitions is -1 though, which I don't understand. This is looking less and less possible in our setup. hmm

Comment: So it sounds like you may have set up the "PARTITION BY" in the external table but didn't add the partitions.  "After creating a partitioned table, alter the table using an ALTER TABLE … ADD PARTITION statement to register new partitions to the external catalog. When you add a partition, you define the location of the subfolder on Amazon S3 that contains the partition data." From: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE.html  I know it seems odd but you need to let Redshift and S3 both know about the partitioning.

Comment: The number of files returned for my update query id from SVL_S3QUERY_SUMMARY matches the number of files in the folder (32). I added the results of SVV_EXTERNAL_PARTITIONS to the end of my question - I think it looks correct? The folder path in S3 is funny though: s3://pathto/events/month=2021-09-01 00:00:00/. I hope it's not that I need ev.month = 'month=2021-09-01 00:00:00'

Comment: Modifying WHERE clause to ev.month = 'month=2021-09-01 00:00:00' updates 0 rows with 0 files scanned reported in svl_s3query_summary.

Comment: What you said about the partitions not being added just clicked - that must be why svl_s3partition reports -1 total partitions. Let me try that!

Comment: The partition was in fact already there, which makes sense because I created it using a crawler that picked up on the partitioning from the folder structure. ERROR:  [2021-09-01 00:00:00,cust_app] Partition entries already exist.

Comment: SVV_EXTERNAL_PARTITIONS lists the partitions for tables.  This is the bit that relates the query WHERE clause to S3 objects.

Comment: So if you go back to experiment #1 and look at the actual execution report, how many rows were scanned from S3? Is this different than the UPDATE query?

Comment: Experiment 1 scans a 82m rows 82m from S3, where the UPDATE scans 31m - though the update never gets to the end. I just ran experiment one again with join conditions "dim_table.root_id = ev.event_id AND dim_table.root_tstamp = ev.collector_tstamp" and the two spectrum pruning filters in a where clause and it actually filled the disk. If I add root_id to the select and then group by 1, experiment 1 completes. I believe this allows Reshift to move the aggregation down to the spectrum layer. I also suspect that parts of the UPDATE plan are happening on cluster, instead of in the spectrum layer.

Comment: I think this is actually good news but let me make sure I got this right.  You re-ran exp #1 but this time you kept the ANSI 89 (no ON clause) structure and it fulled the disks, right?  If so then the EXPLAIN plans should show these differences.  I expect we are looking at a "stupid compiler trick".  The GROUP BY shouldn't change things as the grouping cannot be done until after the join (assuming you didn't remove the "count(1)").  But this is in alignment with how I think this will be fixed - aggregate down to the minimal amount of data from spectrum and use this for the UPDATE.